# How to change title bar text when listeners change on TabPanel elements?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I need change title bar text when change or making tap on icon of TabPanel. I have created

**Bars.js**

```
Ext.define('myapp.view.Myclass', {
   extend: 'Ext.Titlebar',

   config: {
      title: '',
   }
})
```

**Viewport.js**

```
Ext.define('myapp.view.Viewport' , {
extend: 'Ext.TabPanel',

config: {
      tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
      items: [
         {
            xtype: 'myicon1'
         },
         {
            xtype: 'myicon2'
         },
      ]
    }
})
```

and **MyIcon1.js**

```
Ext.define('myapp.view.MyIcon1', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
xtype: 'myicon1',

   config: {
     ...
   }
})
```

So, when I tap on icon's change title dynamically on Titlebar. Thanks I need help.

Answer (score 1):

Just listen to the `activeitemchange` events on the tabpanel :

```
activeitemchange: function( container, value, oldValue, eOpts ){
  ...
}
```

Within this function, just get the name of the new tab from the `value` parameter and set the title to your titlebar.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @TDeBailleul, excuse me, have you email for contact? :)

Comment: See my stackoverflow profile page, then follow the link to my portfolio and then go to the contact page.